# How to get storm door to close properly when door open or closed

Tags: doors, storm-door

So I have a nice solid front door, fitted well against the insulation. The storm door, however, has problems closing depending on the open/close position of the main door. The storm door currently has 2 dampers (one on top and bottom) and both are nearly fully open.

When the door is open, the storm door ends up slamming shut because the damper is wide open.

When the door is shut, the storm door won't close all the way because a pocket of air is trapped between the doors and slows the door down enough it doesn't have enough force to fully close.

How do I fix the doors such that the storm door will fully and softly close no matter which position the front door is in?

Comment: Purely speculating, but I wonder if I spring to pull the door close in conjunction with the dampers will solve this. The dampers keep it smooth and from slamming, but the spring pulled it closed.

Comment: Dampers often have a non-constant damping effect, where the damping goes away at the last moment thus latching the door shut. Perhaps you don't have the dampers positioned properly and this period of reduced damping doesn't match when the door is about to latch?